# R .libPaths() difference between RStudio and command-line R

Tags: r, rstudio

When I run R from the command line:

```
> library(ggplot2)
...
> path.package('ggplot2')
[1] "/home/yang/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.13/ggplot2"
> .libPaths()
[1] "/home/yang/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.13"
[2] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"                
[3] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"                      
[4] "/usr/lib/R/library"                           
> Sys.getenv('R_LIBS_USER')
[1] "~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.13"
```

(Note: that environment variable actually doesn't exist when I check from my shell.)

But from RStudio Server running on the same box, and after logging in as the same user:

```
> path.package('ggplot2')
[1] "/home/yang/R/library/ggplot2"
> .libPaths()
[1] "/home/yang/R/library"              "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"    
[3] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"           "/usr/lib/R/library"               
[5] "/usr/lib/rstudio-server/R/library"
> Sys.getenv('R_LIBS_USER')
[1] "/home/yang/R/library"
```

Can you explain why these are different by default? Is this an RStudio customization? (Why?) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were these installed by the same user with the same permissions?

Comment: RStudio was installed as a Debian package, but it makes each user authenticate as a Linux user and runs things in their environment. In my case the logged-in user is the same as the command-line R user (note the `/home/yang` in the paths).

Comment: Have you checked to see if any of these paths are symlinks to each other?

Comment: Yeah, yhey are not symlinks to each other; they have different contents. I have to re-install all the extensions separately in each environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quick googling got me here:

http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/problems/868-how-to-configure-libpaths

so it looks like RStudio uses its own libs, set in /etc/rstudio/rsession.conf. Why? Who knows.

Comment: JJ Allaire's answer [on Rstudio's support site](http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/questions/204-r-libpaths-difference-between-rstudio-and-command-line-r) sheds some light on the why and a workaround.

Comment: Unfortunately that link now says it is "closed". Booo, hiss. Another  link-mostly answer becomes of minimal value.

Answer (score 8):

Direct answer from the source:

http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/questions/204-r-libpaths-difference-between-rstudio-and-command-line-r

> Hi there,
>
> Yes, we have a custom R_LIBS_USER setting which is intended to make it
>   easier to upgrade the server to a new version of R without requiring
>   that every user rename their library directory and/or re-build their
>   packages. That way the administrator can do an upgrade without fearing
>   that they'll break their user's working environment (realize that this
>   could also be accomplished by writing an upgrade script that does the
>   requisite rename/rebuild for each user).
>
> Fully agree that this isn't necessarily desirable in all cases. Here
>   is what you can do to work around it:
>
> The Rtudio Server R_LIBS_USER is controlled by the following setting
>   in /etc/rstudio/rsession.conf:
>
> ```
> r-libs-user=~/R/library
> ```
>
> This variable supports the same wildcarding as R_LIBS_USER (as
>   described here:
>   http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/libPaths.html)
>   so you could change this to the following to make RStudio behave just
>   like console R:
>
> ```
> r-libs-user=~/R/%p-library/%v
> ```
>
> (note I believe that is the right syntax to reproduce the directory
>   shown in your output above but you'll definitely want to double check
>   that)
>
> Hope that clears things up and that you can get things configured as
>   you'd like. Let us know if you have other questions or if this doesn't
>   work as described.
>
> J.J.