# RStudio shows a different $PATH variable

Tags: r, rstudio, path-variables

Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16049259/rstudio-different-library-path-to-command-line-r-r-libs-user) question, but I don't know the startup process of RStudio to tell if the problems are the same. I'm using RStudio Desktop v0.99.442 on Linux. From the console inside RStudio, I run

```
system("echo $PATH")
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

However, my real `$PATH` (which I see when I `echo $PATH` from the console) has a lot of other programs on it that I'd like to be able to call using system() from R. For example, in my .bashrc, I have tabix appended to `$PATH`.

The weird thing is when I run the same command from a R session within the console, I get

```
system("echo $PATH")
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games;/path/to/bcftools-1.2/htslib-1.2.1/tabix
```

which is correct. So there is a difference between a R session inside RStudio and a R session in the console. They do not load the same environment variables. How do I get RStudio to use the correct version of $PATH?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you start R from the command line and then run `system(echo $PATH)`, you are inheriting the Bash environment from your command line session. When you launch RStudio from, say, the Dock or Finder on a Mac or as a system application in Ubuntu, and not from the command line, RStudio does not gets its environment from your `/.bashrc`. Instead it will get the environment variables from system-wide settings. How it finds those system settings will depend on the operating system.

### Ubuntu

See [this explanation of environment variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) in Ubuntu, especially the [section on desktop applications](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Launching_desktop_application_with_an_environment_variable).

According to that explanation:

> You can add an environment variable to an application by editing its .desktop file. For example, to run "digiKam" with the environment variable APPMENU_DISPLAY_BOTH=1, find the corresponding digikam.desktop file and add the setting of the variable, via the env command, to the entry "Exec":

The RStudio `.desktop` file will be in `~/.local/share/applications/` or `/usr/share/applications/` (most likely the latter). Edit that file to include this line:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games;/path/to/bcftools-1.2/htslib-1.2.1/tabix
```

### Mac

System-wide environment variables are set by the Launch Agent and not by Bash. Exactly how you set the environment variables for applications launched from the Finder will depend on your version of Mac OS X. This [answer might help](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51677/how-to-set-path-for-finder-launched-applications).

The way that I do this is to add a file, `~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.username.envvariables.plist` with these contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.username.envvariables</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>sh</string>
      <string>-c</string>
      <string>
        launchctl setenv PATH /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games;/path/to/bcftools-1.2/htslib-1.2.1/tabix
      </string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

You will then have to load that file:

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.username.envvariables.plist
```

You may have to restart the Finder:

```
killall -KILL Dock
```

Then restart RStudio.

Comment: I am using Linux (Ubuntu v15.04). Updated my question.

Comment: @JoshBradley: I've updated the answer to include Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you. Adding the absoluate path `env PATH=/path/to/bcftools-1.2/htslib-1.2.1/tabix` to the .desktop file works. For a better solution, I tried setting it to expand the current PATH by using `env PATH=${PATH}` or `env PATH=$PATH` but the RStudio PATH variable is not correct then.

Comment: @LincolnMullen Hi Lincoln, you solution really solved my issue. So thank you very much. At the same time, can I ask how can we also add dyld_library_path in rstudio using this method? Since system('echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH') returns nothing while it returns some paths in terminal. Thank yoU!

Answer (score 5):

I have met the same problem. Instead of Lincoln's answer, I manually set the correct environment inside RStudio console by

```
Sys.setenv(PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games;/path/to/bcftools-1.2/htslib-1.2.1/tabix")
```

in this case.

PATH that R is using could also checked in console by

```
Sys.getenv()
```

Comment: Is this change persistent or valid for the current session?

Comment: When I put this in my .Renviron, it works, but RStudio still pre-pends `/usr/local/bin` to the front, which is not what I want

Comment: @HarryM Have you figured out a work around? I'm also struggeling with rstudio prepending $PATH by /usr/bin

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue (on MAC) by adding PATH to ~/.Renviron 
You can run this:

```
$ touch ~/.Renviron | R_PATH="PATH=$PATH" | echo $R_PATH >  ~/.Renviron
```

and restart Rstudio. Now you should have the same $PATH in both cases.

Comment: This approach causes problems in parallell processing with `doParallel`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59750496/doparallelmakecluster-causes-failed-to-discover-a-secure-download-method-er/59750497#59750497) for more.