# doParallel::makeCluster causes "Failed to discover a secure download method." error

Tags: r

When attempting to make a cluster, I encounter the following error in Rstudio (1.2.5033) but not in the Terminal (Mac). It occurs regardless of whether I run the script inside or outside a project session.

```
> makeCluster(2, outfile="")
Error in secureDownloadMethod() : 
  Failed to discover a secure download method.
Calls: source ... setPackratModeOn -> afterPackratModeOn -> secureDownloadMethod
Execution halted
sh: rm: command not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently attempted to get Rstudio to read environment variables from `.bash_profile` and not only from `.Renviron`. I therefore added `PATH="PATH=$PATH"` to `.Renviron`. Removing `PATH="PATH=$PATH"` solved the problem.

The reason Rstudio and the Terminal behaved differently, was because the Terminal reads in `.bash_profile` environment variables into an R session and hence did not encounter this problem.