# Sys.getenv can't find environment variable

Tags: r, macos, shell

I'm using MacOS Catalina v10.15.7

From the terminal I edit .bash_profile and add
`export POSTMARKAPP_API_KEY="12345678"`

`source .bash_profile`

`env`

I see: POSTMARKAPP_API_KEY=12345678

From RStudio console the environment variable is empty

```
Sys.getenv("POSTMARKAPP_API_KEY")
[1] ""
```

Other environment variables have values, but echo seems to execute the command, ie:

```
~/: echo$SHELL
-bash: echo/bin/bash: No such file or directory
```

How can I successfully read `POSTMARKAPP_API_KEY` from RStudio's Console?

Comment: Did you run open R after you made the change or before? Make sure to open it after because programs inherit the environment variables at startup. Also did you launch R from the same terminal session where you made the change? If it's in your `bash_profile` you'll likely need to log out and log back in for it to take effect for all applications.

Comment: From within RStudio I have restarted R. I have also closed and re-restarted RStudio. The environment variable in question is still empty.

Comment: Did you log out and log back in? When you make a change to an environment variable, it will only effect that particular terminal session. When you make the change in `.base_profile`, it only takes effect when you start new terminal sessions or log in to the OS. Restarting R inside of R Studio will just get the same environment variables that RStudio itself was launched with. It will not update them.

Comment: Since .bash_profile is run for every new terminal session, the environment variable is visible. Other environment variables are visible from RStudio's Console. How do I get a new one to be visible?

Comment: Ah, if you are not launching Rstudio from a bash shell, then it won't inherit those system variables. Launching from the dock or restarting the R console in RStudio do not involve bash. If you want to set system variables for Rstudio to use, see this existing question for the right way to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31121645/rstudio-shows-a-different-path-variable

Comment: Yes. I just read something similar here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/opening-rstudio-on-mac-using-finder-doesnt-pick-up-environment-variables/61714 Editing my .Rprofile seems easiest. Problem solved.