# Why two different users see different R package locations in Linux?

Tags: linux, r, package

I have two different Linux (Ubuntu) users `azg` and `deploy`, the first is my personal username and the second is the global user to deploy released software. I develop under user `azg` and eventually install R packages which I use in my R implementations.

The problem I have is that the user `deploy` doesn't see the same packages that `azg` sees. Checking the install locations I see completely different results. User `deploy` gets:

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/site-library"      
[3] "/usr/lib/R/library"           
>
```

and user `azg` gets:

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "/home/azg/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0"
[2] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"              
[3] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"                    
[4] "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

and the end result is that my released software doesn't work because of missing libraries. Is there a way to have all packages in a single location system-wide? Separate question is why the `site-library` locations appear in a single line in one and in separate lines in the other? does it actually matter?

Comment: See the [Managing Libraries](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Managing-libraries) section of the _R Installation and Administration_ manual.

Comment: Are you using rstudio server?

Comment: Yes I am using rstudio server only as user `azg`.

Comment: Be aware that rstudio server will not necessarily be picking up .rprofile and the like. You may need to invoke /etc/environment. The point is the two users will have different experiences.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129213/r-libpaths-difference-between-rstudio-and-command-line-r contains some info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple-enough way around this (esp. on Ubuntu which has littler) is to use the example script 'install.r' that ships with littler.

It defaults to installing `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library`.

And with a patch we got into R proper, group-write permissions are now 'inherited' by directories created (by R) therein, so if you make your user members of the group owning the directory, you are set.

And yes, that is what we do at work where multiple users share servers via RStudio :)